# Selenium driver is entering value in the text box but it is getting cleared

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am stuck in this issue. Webdriver is able to enter the value in the text box and then the value is getting cleared

I tried this to resolve this issue with the below logic but unfortunately this one is even not working.Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated

```
var count =0;

do {

_webHelper.PerformWebDriverAction(getTxtBox_ProductionDate(), INPUT, ProductionDate);

count++;

} while (!_webHelper.IsTextBoxFilled(getTxtBox_ProductionDate()) && count<10);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try these ways to set value

#1 Clear, enter value and Send tab key to move control out of input

```
element.clear()
element.sendKeys("value"+ Keys.TAB);
```

#2 using Javascript

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='arguments[1]';", element,value)
```

#3 using Actions

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().sendKeys("text to set").perform();
```